# Model SIR Fitting

Tags: python, model, curve-fitting

I've written a program to solve the model SIR system of equations using Euler method. I would like to find the parameters beta and gamma that can fit to some experimental data.

```
def SIR(I0,beta,gama,dt,tmax):

    N=int(tmax/dt)+1 
    T=zeros([N+1,3])
    T[0,0]=1-I0
    T[0,1]=I0
    for i in range(N):
        T[i+1,0]=T[i,0]-dt*beta*T[i,0]*T[i,1]
        T[i+1,1]=T[i,1]+dt*T[i,1]*(beta*T[i,0]-gama)
        T[i+1,2]=T[i,2]+dt*gama*T[i,1]
    return(T)
```

I tried to use `scipy.optimize.curvefit` which only works for simple function that return an expression. How can I use it for a function that returns an array?

for a simple function it works perfectly

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

from matplotlib.pyplot import *

fluo = [ 16059919, 13988972, 6697838, 4273231, 3259139, 3032325, 3153090 ]

conc = [ 5, 10, 30, 50, 75, 100, 130 ]

fluo = np.array(fluo)

conc = np.array(conc)

def model(L, Ka, n):

    F0 = fluo[0] # On fixe F0, c'est la première valeur de F
    Fc = fluo[5] # On fixe Fc, c'est la dernière valeur de F

    #F est exprimé en fonction du reste
    F = (Fc * Ka * (L**n) + F0) / (Ka * (L**n) + 1)

    #On retourne F
    return F

popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, conc, fluo, maxfev=3000)

print(popt)

plot(conc, fluo, 'rp') # Trace fluo = f(conc)
plot(conc, model(conc, popt[0], popt[1]), "b") 

grid(True)

show()
```